# How to configure Compass build with rbenv in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, compass-sass, rbenv

Trying to build a SASS file under OSX with [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) and the default Compass build file results in:

```
/bin/sh: compass: command not found
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 127]
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Compass/Compass.sublime-build` file:

```
"osx": {
    "path": "/usr/local/bin:/Users/USERNAME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
},
```

You may have to restart Sublime.

Comment: Instead of `/Users/USERNAME` you can use `{HOME}`.