# Compass error: sublime text

Tags: installation, sublimetext3, rbenv, compass

Newby question.
I'm receiving the following error in Sublime Text 3:

[ERROR] compass not found. Make sure it exists in your PATH.

I installed Compass already, it's in my Packages folder of my Sublime Text 3 folder.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: I run OSX 10.11.3 and I found my answer right here on [How to configure Compass build with rbenv in Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712801/how-to-configure-compass-build-with-rbenv-in-sublime-text-2/13712802#13712802)

I had to add edit my Compass.sublime-build file in my Packages folder of Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed the [Compass](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Compass) plugin for Sublime, which provides a [build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) for converting SASS files to CSS. However, as stated in the Prerequisites in the documentation, it depends on [`compass`](http://compass-style.org/), which is a Ruby gem. Therefore, you need to install [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org), then follow the instructions [here](http://compass-style.org/install/).

Comment: Thnx for pointing me in the right direction! I have: 
'ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405)' installed. 
I successfully installed rubygems-update-2.6.4.
Homebrew installed. Successfully installed rbenv 2.1.5. Successfully installed compass-1.0.3. Still getting my error, I'm lost.

Comment: @S.Wannsee what does `which -a compass` return? Anything?

Comment: it states /Users/Username/.rbenv/shims/compass and 2nd line
/usr/local/bin/compass. However I managed to get it to work by editing my Compass.sublime-build file in my packages folder of ST3. I've edited my own initial question. Thnx for your help.

Comment: @S.Wannsee glad you got it to work, that's exactly what I was going to recommend once you found the path to `compass`.